# Detect latin1 characters in utf8 string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I get data from the database that is utf8 encoded. But somehow some old data contains latin1 characters.

So this

```
$encod = mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', true);
```

always is correct.

Is it safe to always use utf8_decode() to check for latin1 characters like 'äöüß'???

```
$string = utf8_decode($string);
$search = Array(" ", "ä", "ö", "ü", "ß", "."); //,"/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/");
$replace = Array("-", "ae", "oe", "ue", "ss", "-"); //,"Ae","Oe","Ue");
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, strtolower($string));
```

Regards

Comment: how about `mb_detect_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1,UTF-8', true);` ?

Comment: @ajreal the string I get from the database is 'Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤' `code` mb_detect_encoding($this->_name, 'ISO-8859-1,UTF-8', true);`code` says 'ISO-8859-1' and utf8_decode($string) gives 'äääää', what shall I do?

Comment: try search for iconv, mb conversion over php manual/SO, should have few questions discuss before here

Comment: @ajreal ok I'll read that, `code`mb_convert_encoding($this->_name, 'ISO-8859-1');`code` works for all characters accept ß so I'll try iconv now

Comment: @ajreal `mb_detect_encoding($string,'auto',true)` did work for me. But the main problem in the conversion was `strtolower($string)` as it is not save to convert special characters to lower with this function

Comment: how about this ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

Comment: @areal I used mb_strtolower now and it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work without the `utf8_encoding`:

```
<?php
   $string = "äöüß";
   $search = Array(" ", "ä", "ö", "ü", "ß", "."); //,"/Ä/","/Ö/","/Ü/");
   $replace = Array("-", "ae", "oe", "ue", "ss", "-"); //,"Ae","Oe","Ue");
   $string = str_replace($search, $replace, strtolower($string));
   echo $string;
?>
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/HGTyHkBU

Comment: not from me ;-), but also not a really good answer as the string you put into $string is dependent on the character encoding of the file you save the code to. My data is coming from the datbase and is utf8 encoded but contains latin1 characters like 'Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤' which is utf8_decoded = äääää

Answer (score -2):

Use htmlspecialchars(); it is more safer for work.
More info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: not a good answer as data is not needed to convert special characters to HTML entities ;-)